# How to return form field errors to template rendered in a different django view

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I have a django bootstrap 4 template (`wordcloud.html`) that contains a form. The form was originally created as raw html within `wordcloud.html`, and the view for that template populates the fields. The form (`create_wordcloud_form`) uses post to send the data to a different view (`create_wordcloud_view.py`). The original developer didn't use django's built in template/form/view structure, so there is no form.py nor a form template.

The issue I need to address is validating the form. It has to be server-side validation, as one of the fields needs to be tested against one of the databases to prevent duplicate fields.

Do I need to refactor the whole mess into the standard django template/form/view idiom using crispy-forms, or is there a way to use what I already have and return some error messages from the view that processes the form data?

The code for validating the fields is easy. I am not sure how to structure the return statement in the event there are field errors, since `wordcloud.html` is rendered in a different view.

create_wordcloud_view:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='post')
class CreateWordCloud(View):  
     
    def post(self, request):
        logger.debug("CreateWordCloud START")  
        q_dict = request.POST
        logger.debug("q_dict=%s" % q_dict)
        sources = []
        filters = {}
        cloud_name = None
        for key in q_dict:
            logger.debug("key=%s" % key)
            if key == 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
                continue
            if key in ["Titles", "Descriptions", "Comments", "Translations", "Text"]:
                sources.append(key)
            elif key == 'wordcloud_name':
                cloud_name = q_dict['wordcloud_name']
            else:
                values = q_dict.getlist(key)
                if len(values) == 1:
                    filters[key] = values[0]
                else:
                    filters[key] = values

        # Need to add field validation here
        # 1. Must have at least one source
        # 2. wordcloud_name must not be in the table of wordclouds
        # 3. Alert user that no words were found for the combination of sources
        # and filters selected

        from wordcloud.tasks import create_wordcloud_task_3
        create_wordcloud_task_3(None, cloud_name, sources, filters=filters)
        # If the form data is valid and more than a few words are returned from
        # create_wordcloud_task_3, then redirect to wordcloud.html
        
        return redirect("/memorabilia/wordcloud.html", permanent=False)
        
        # If form is invalid or no words returned from create_wordcloud_task_3, 
        # return to wordcloud.html with original data and appropriate field error
        # messages.
        return ????
```

create_wordcloud_form (a snippet from the `wordcloud.html` template):

```
    <div id="wordcloud_form" style="display: none;">
        <form action="/wordcloud/ajax/create_wordcloud/" class="was-validated" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>First, select the source of words:</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="source_text" name="Text">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="source_text">Text</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="source_translation" name="Translations">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="source_translation">Translations</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="source_titles" name="Titles">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="source_titles">Titles</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="source_descriptions" name="Descriptions">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="source_descriptions">Descriptions</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="source_comments" name="Comments">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="source_comments">Comments</label>
                </div>
                <span>{{ form_sources_required }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-row mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Second, filter documents based on the metadata, if desired:</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            {% for category in categories %}
                {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3  %}
                <div class="form-row">
                {% endif %}    
                        <div class="col">
                        <label>{{ category.label }}</label>
                        <select class="selectpicker" name="{{ category.label }}" multiple data-size="10">
                            {% for option in category.options %}
                                <option>{{ option }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}    
                        </select>
                        </div>
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}    
                </div>
                {% endif%}
            {% endfor %}
            
            <div class="form-row mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="wordcloud_name">Finally, give your wordcloud a name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="wordcloud_name" class="form-control" id="wordcloud_name" placeholder="Enter your wordcloud name">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ form_cloud_name_required }} {{ form_duplicate_cloud_name_error }}</div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-row mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>       
    </div>
```

A picture of the rendered form:
[image: form]

Comment: You can just use the form for rendering errors and validation if you want, while leaving the form rendering as the current manually written HTML that you have (might need to change the `name` attributes to match if needed). Although I would advice if you are up for it go for refractoring :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a django form with the same field names as your html form.
After you submit the form you can check if it valid:

```
form = YourForm(request.POST)
# check whether it's valid:
if form.is_valid():
    ...
```

Then if the form is not valid you can show the errors in your template like so:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="wordcloud_name">Finally, give your wordcloud a name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="wordcloud_name" class="form-control" id="wordcloud_name" placeholder="Enter your wordcloud name">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ form.wordcloud_name.errors }}</div>
                </div>
```